# IIS 7.5 HTTP Error 404

Tags: iis

**Error Summary**
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
**Detailed Error Information**
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    MapRequestHandler
Handler ASPClassic
Error Code  0x80070002

What could be the possible cause for this error? I've been cracking what could be wrong. I have set up my websites and IIS7.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to access content on a server that is running Internet Information Services (IIS) 7.0, 7.5, or 8.0 by using the HTTP protocol, IIS returns a numeric code that indicates the status of the response. The HTTP status code is recorded in the IIS log. Additionally, the HTTP status code may be displayed in the client browser.

**4xx - Client error** :

These HTTP status codes indicate that an error occurred and that the client browser appears to be at fault. For example, the client browser may have requested a page that does not exist. Or, the client browser may not have provided valid authentication information.

[image]
The classic version of `ASP` is not installed by default. Because of this, you might see `HTTP 404` errors when you try to browse to an ASP page on your server, or you might see the source code for your ASP page displayed in your browser window.

> Both of these error conditions are created when configuration settings
>   that are used to define the environment for classic ASP are not
>   installed.

Steps to install are listed [**here**](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis)

Edit 1 :

Check the application pool and applications associated.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is that Classic ASP isn't installed? The OP's error message states that the ASPClassic module raised the 404 event, so I think it's a misconfiguration or application code that's doing this rather the server not having the right modules installed.

Comment: I have already done what is on the link. what about application pool and applications associated? can you enlighten me more sir?

Comment: edit webconfig with question for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Could you be restricted because of your request size limit?

You'll get a `404.0` if your request size goes beyond the limit you've set in the `web.config`

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4000000000" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Comment: my web.config doesnt contain request size limit. heres the code <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="pldtsearch.asp" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Comment: Remember that even if you don't have the section in your web.config, IIS will find the setting for it in your `applicationhost` config file. So try to add the request filtering section, then you can at least rule that out.